# deserialize JSON to an ArrayList with Flexjson (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, flexjson

I want to deserialize this json data into an ArrayList

```
{"users":[{"username":"jon@jafprod.com","pw":"123456","data":""},{"username":"fred@jones.com","pw":"abcde","data":""}]}
```

this is the class

```
public class UserClass
{
    public String email;
    public String pw;
    public JSONObject data;
}
```

My attempts such as:

```
UserClass users = new JSONDeserializer<UserClass>().use("users", UserClass.class)
                    .deserialize( resultStr, Array.class );
```

but always result in a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lflexjson/JSONDeserializer;

Comment: why you don't use Gson?

Comment: This worked but returned an ArrayList of HashMap not UserClass

Comment: JSONDeserializer<List<UserClass>> deserializer = new JSONDeserializer<List<UserClass>>();
      List<UserClass> users = deserializer.deserialize(resultStr);